# Consumir a Segurança de uma API para aplicação Web MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Tenho uma API para poder logar(AspNet Identity) na aplicação WEB MVC.

1. Acesso a aplicação WEB MVC(Tela de Login).
2. Chamo a API passando email e senha, que foi informado na aplicação WEB MVC.
3. API retorna com o Token(Bearer).

A Dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para autorizar o acesso as classes da aplicação WEB com a clausula [Authorize], considerando o Token que retorno da API?

--- Atualizando com o Código --

-- Método Que chama minha API

```
 private async Task<List<LoginModel>> GetUserNameByemailRestSharp(string email)
    {
        List<LoginModel> lst = new List<LoginModel>();

        object param = new { Email = email };

        try
        {
            IRestResponse restResponse = await APIIdentity.ResponseAPIPost_RestSharp("/api/Account/GetUserNameByemail", param);

            var token = JToken.Parse(restResponse.Content);
            var obj = JObject.Parse((string)token.ToString());

            lst.Add(new LoginModel { UserName = obj["UserName"].ToString(), Email = obj["Email"].ToString(), Password = obj["Password"].ToString()});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lst.Add(new LoginModel { UserName = "", Email = "", Password = "" });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

-- Controller que a tela de login da aplicação WEB MVC(Via Ajax) chama passando, email e senha

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> getLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        List<LoginModel> lstUser = null;
        object result = null;

        try
        {
            lstUser = await GetUserNameByemailRestSharp(email);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstUser[0].UserName))
            {
                var lstToken = await GetToken(lstUser[0].UserName, password);

                if (lstToken[0].ToString() != "200")
                {
                    result = new { StatusCode = lstToken[0].ToString(), Decription = lstToken[1].ToString() };
                }
                else
                {
                   //Token que retornado da API
                    result = new { StatusCode = lstToken[0].ToString(), Decription = "" };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = new { StatusCode = "400", Decription = "E-mail não consta na base de dados!" };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new { StatusCode = "400", Decription = "E-mail não consta na base de dados!" };
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

O Objeto **Result** contem o Token Bearer, como faço para autenticar o atributo *[Authorize]* da minha aplicação WEB MVC que esta fora do projeto API considerando esse Token?

Comment: Não está muito clara a pergunta. De que Token você está falando? É um JWT, SAML, etc.. Onde está o código? Veja esse link para ajudá-lo a melhorar sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

o [Authorize] define que o usuário autenticado os pontos onde somente os usuários autenticados podem ter acesso.

Quando você decora o clases e/ou métodos com [Authorize] você está definindo que somente usuários autenticados podem ter acesso ao escopo.

Dependendo da complexidade do seu projeto, você deve combinar a autorização com outros parâmetros como Roles e Usuários permitidos. Você pode por exemplo definir que um método está autorizado somente para usuários com regras de administração ou superusuário, conforme abaixo:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, SuperUser")]
```

Após a autenticação, dependendo de como está configurado seu projeto e as separações de camadas, o usuário autenticado será autorizado de forma transparente através dos Cookies ou envio do Token. Usando o Identity você também pode trabalhar as Roles e Claims diretamente no processo.

Aqui [Autorização baseadas em função](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2) você pode ter mais informações sobre este processo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, porém preciso de ajuda em uma processo antes desse., atualizei o meu post.

Comment: Anderson, para isso, você precisa criar uma relação de confiança entre seu client (projeto web) e seu provedor de identidade. Dependendo do padrão adotado você deverá configurar seu cliente com informações do provedor de identidade para ter esta relação, ou seja, assim seu client irá autorizar as requisições com tokens do provedor de identidade, já que ele conhece este provedor. Dê uma olhada em [Proteger microsserviços .NET e aplicativos Web](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/)